# Share state between different actor types

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I created two actors Actor1 and Actor2 in one project and registered them in Program.cs:

```
ActorRuntime.RegisterActorAsync<Actor1>();
ActorRuntime.RegisterActorAsync<Actor2>();
```

but in runtime I see that each of them hosted in separate Actor Services. When I save some data in Reliable Collections via StateManager in Actor1, this state is not available for Actor2.

Is it possible to share state between different actor types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it looks like you are using actors in wrong way. You should register one actor type per host process. For example

```
ActorRuntime.RegisterActorAsync<Actor1>((context, actorType) => 
                    new ActorService(
                        context, 
                        actorType,
                        () => new Actor1()))
.GetAwaiter()
.GetResult();
```

If you want communication between actors, you need to create actor instance and call a method on its interface to save data. Then, if you want to save the same data in another actor, you need to create another instance. *Actros by design are unique, separate entities.* You can do it from one place and create two actors and save the data separately or you can create second actor from the first. For example

```
var actor1Proxy = ActorProxy.Create<IActor1>(actorId, new Uri("fabric:/MyApp/Actor1"));
var actor2Proxy = ActorProxy.Create<IActor2>(actorId, new Uri("fabric:/MyApp/Actor2"));

actor1Proxy.SaveData(data);
actor2Proxy.SaveData(data);
```

Probably, you need a reliable service to store your data. Please read [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-platform/) and [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-get-started/) articles for more information about how to use actors.

Comment: Yes in general you should host actors in different processes as you can upgrade one independently from the other. However, you can host more than one actor types in the same process.

Comment: @VipulM-MSFT yep, we even have [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38732867/2152061) about that.